# formatting my semicolon database properly with flatfile (text) php

Tags: php

This is my output to my `data.txt` file now...

```
test1;test2
test3;test4
```

this is what I would like it to be

```
MSG 1;test1;test2;
MSG 2;test3;test4;
```

**My html**

```
<form action="messageprocessor.php" method="POST">

    Message:
      <textarea name="field1"></textarea>
    To:<input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

**My PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . ';' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}           
?>
```

Everything works perfectly but I'm trying to understand how to output to my data file to the way I want it above. Can anyone help me in this area? William

Comment: so basically add `msg x` to each line? first you'd have to parse the entire file and figure out what the largest `msg` is already, then output one larger. which begs the question,why use a file in the first place? use a proper database and you get all the locking/ID generation for "free". If you can't/won't use a client/server rdbms, there's always sqlite.

Comment: I love MySQL however all of this generates from the SCD of a supercomputer and they don't want a lot of routines running... It was all I could do to beg them to put on the apache server as they didn't even want me to use php. So none of this goes on the internet and the data file is easier because everything becomes self contained in one directory. I miss MySQL  commands at this point and am lost most of the time but grateful to work on a flat file and to learn some of these intricacies. But mostly grateful for the help on this server... thanks